# Gap & Islands - POSTGRESQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, gaps-and-islands

I have the following table

```
Name PathID PathLength PathStepNum
A      1      5          1
A      1      5          2
B      1      5          3
C      1      5          4
A      1      5          5
Y      2      3          1
Z      2      3          2
Z      2      3          3
```

And I need to get

```
PathID   PathName
1        A x2 > B x1 > C x1 > A x1
2        Y x1 > Z x2
```

So essentially what I need to do is: for each PathID, count the number of consecutive occurrences of Name, and stitch together Name + NumConsecOccurrences in the order of the PathStepNum.

Any thoughts?
Thank you!

Comment: And where does `x1` and `x2` come from?

Comment: @GordonLinoff - those are the number of consecutive occurrences (i.e. x2 = 2 times)

Answer (score 1):

A classic solution with window and aggregate functions:

```
select 
    pathid, 
    string_agg(format('%s x%s', name, count), ' > ' order by min) as path
from (
    select 
        pathid, name, min(pathstepnum), 
        count(*)
    from (
        select 
            pathid, name, pathstepnum, 
            sum(mark) over w as grp
        from (
            select 
                pathid, name, pathstepnum, 
                (name <> lag(name, 1, name) over w)::int as mark
            from my_table
            window w as (partition by pathid order by pathstepnum)
            ) s
        window w as (partition by pathid order by pathstepnum)
        ) s
    group by pathid, name, grp
    ) s
group by pathid

 pathid |           path            
--------+---------------------------
      1 | A x2 > B x1 > C x1 > A x1
      2 | Y x1 > Z x2
(2 rows)
```

[DbFiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=78805bd98aa8b0ef642ba005ea3b5869)

It seems however, that this can be achieved in a client application (in python, java or whatever is used) in a simpler and more efficient way.

Comment: Hey @klin - this looks perfect. However, the only issue I'm having is that ORDER BY MIN in the top string_agg there is not supported for my version of POSTGRESQL - I'm only on 8.0. Do you know how to break that ORDER BY MIN out so this runs for this version?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not able to test this in 8.0 but you can try to move this `order by` from the aggregate to the subquery like in [this example.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=9ae273a633cddaf5e3fb324544a12300)

Comment: Ahh now I'm getting a syntax error on "w" in SUM(mark) OVER w AS grp...sigh haha. No worries if you can't get too into the weeds with 8.0 - you've provided a really elegant solution @klin